# How to find the sum of certain column values ​by conditions from another one?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

There are 2 columns. 1st one with values in date format DD.MM.YYYY, 2nd one with integer values. How to produce the sum of the numbers from the second column according to the conditions of matching the month from the first? For ex Im interesting in sum of the values ​​that match MONTH () = 11?

[image]

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that your original data is in a sheet called `Sheet1`, that you have headers in A1 and B1 and that the data set you posted is in A2:B14 with nothing written in the cells A15:B. In a new sheet, enter this formula in cell A1:

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({DATE(YEAR(Sheet1!A2:A),MONTH(Sheet1!A2:A),1),B2:B},"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'MONTH', SUM(Col2) 'TOTAL' FORMAT Col1 'mmm yyyy'"))`

This `QUERY` will result in two headers (which you can change within the `LABEL` section of the `QUERY` if you like) and all results for all months/years present in the data set.

The `QUERY` acts on a virtual array which first converts all dates in Sheet1!A2:A into new `DATE`s based on the month and year from the original dates but all falling on the first of the month. This allows the `SUM`s to be grouped in the `QUERY`. Then the `QUERY`'s `FORMAT` section converts those normalized dates to show you just the month and year portion.

Adjust the sheet name and referenced ranges to fit the sheet name and data range of your actual data.

**NOTE** (after learning that OP's locale is Russia):

This version will work for your locale...

`=ArrayFormula(QUERY({DATE(YEAR(Sheet1!A2:A); MONTH(Sheet1!A2:A);1) \ Sheet1!B2:B}; "Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'MONTH', SUM(Col2) 'TOTAL' FORMAT Col1 'mmm yyyy'"))`

Comment: Big thanks for the quick and detailed answer.
But Ive got syntax error after pasting that formula.
Mb I need to convert date data to 'mmm yyyy' formatting at first?

Comment: Still have an error 
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Cj5ShiWv2jWHL_6zwK-TQiIYSEslNXSW-6mc4qn_G1A

Comment: I updated the formula for your locale (Russia) on your spreadsheet, after renaming "Sheet2" as "Erik Help"). The new formula versions; `=ArrayFormula(QUERY({DATE(YEAR(Sheet1!A2:A);MONTH(Sheet1!A2:A);1)\Sheet1!B2:B};"Select Col1, SUM(Col2) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 LABEL Col1 'MONTH', SUM(Col2) 'TOTAL' FORMAT Col1 'mmm yyyy'"))`

Comment: Ty too much! Now it works

Comment: How could I edit this formula to get a sum of values for only one month from list?

Comment: That is a separate question. In an effort to be an easy-to-use resource for all visitors in the future, the forum rules are that only one question should be asked per post. Please ask you new question in a new post. I will try to keep an eye out for that new post.

Answer (score 0):

#### Monthly Sums

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  let sums = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach((r => {
    let p = r[0].split('.').filter((e,i) => i > 0).reduce((a,c,idx) => {
      if(idx > 0) a += '.';
      a += c;
      return a;
    });
    if(!sums.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      sums[p]= r[1];
      sums.pA.push(p);
    } else {
      sums[p] += r[1]
    }
  }));
  let html = '<style> td,th{border: 1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Month</th><th>Sum</th></tr>';
  sums.pA.forEach(p => {
    html += `<tr><td>${p}</td><td>${sums[p]}</td></tr>`
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Monthly Sums')
}
```

Data:

[image]

Sums Dialog:

[image]

#### Added Monthly Sums to osh

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  osh.clear();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).getValues();
  let sums = {pA:[]};
  vs.forEach((r => {
    let p = r[0].split('.').filter((e,i) => i > 0).reduce((a,c,idx) => {
      if(idx > 0) a += '.';
      a += c;
      return a;
    });
    if(!sums.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      sums[p]= r[1];
      sums.pA.push(p);
    } else {
      sums[p] += r[1]
    }
  }));
  let html = '<style> td,th{border: 1px solid black;}</style><table><tr><th>Month</th><th>Sum</th></tr>';
  let arr = [['Month','Sums']];
  sums.pA.forEach(p => {
    html += `<tr><td>${p}</td><td>${sums[p]}</td></tr>`
    arr.push([`${p}`,`${sums[p]}`])
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html),'Monthly Sums');
  osh.getRange(1,1,arr.length,arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
}
```

Comment: Works fine, thank you. But I need to place received arr values into new Range.
Could you pls help me? I'm not good at understanding specifics of working with arrays

Comment: Added monthly sums output to osh

Comment: Returned an error:
TypeError: r[0].split is not a function

Comment: It's the same code as last time.  Anyway that was 3 days ago I've forgotten all about it.  So you can debug yourself.